# How can we sum two or more UUID numbers (Hexadecimals) in XSLT2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been trying to find a solution to sum two or more `**UUID**` variables(*Hexadecimals* *in* ***`XSLT2.0`***,

Lets say we have examples like:

```
005eb9ed-1347-4ca3-bb29-9bc0db64e1ab

f5276600-a2b6-4ff6-a90e-b31fe19dae41

7d35fb7c-da5b-4830-b598-4f347a04dceb
```

I wanna sum these numbers (treat as a number) or lets say transform them into numbers then sum them and change the results as hexadecimals again.

How this could be possible with **`XSLT2.0`** ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:bin="http://expath.org/ns/binary">

<xsl:function name="f:toInt" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="uuid" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:variable name="b64Input" as="bin:hex(translate($uuid, '-', ''))"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="bin:unpack-unsigned-integer($b64Input, 0, bin:length($b64Input))"/>
</xsl:function>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="f:toInt(uuid['7c637c0c-7703-4389-ba52-02997a055bd7']) + f:toInt(uuid['f5276600-a2b6-4ff6-a90e-b31fe19dae41'])"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**UPDATED with example xslt code**

Comment: What do you mean by "sum" - concatenate? Or sum (treating them as numbers)?

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your expected output given your input. Good luck.

Comment: yes we need to treat or transform them into numbers, then sum these numbers and write the results as it was given ( hexadecimals)

Comment: UUIDs are 128-bit numbers. Even if you could transform your above input into numbers and add them, the result may exceed this, and so you wouldn't have a UUID as a result. What would expect the output to look like for your given input above? Thanks

Comment: As you can see the numbers are seperated by blocks with "-" so my idea was to sum each of the groups among themselves, then combine them later on like in the examples. lets say sum the first group first  "005eb9ed" "f5276600" "7d35fb7c" then the second then the third, last of all the fourth one. Then combine them with "-" as a result of hexadecimal again.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of the EXPath Binary library, assuming an implementation that supports xs:integer values of sufficient size, you can convert the values to numbers like this:

```
<xsl:function name="f:toInt" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="uuid" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:variable name="b64Input" select="bin:hex(translate($uuid, '-', ''))"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="bin:unpack-unsigned-integer(
                          $b64input, 0, bin:length($b64input))"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Then add the two values:

```
f:toInt(uuid[1]) + f:toInt(uuid[2])
```

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for your solution, but i couldnt execute it. I think for bin: prefix we use xmlns:hex="http://expath.org/spec/binary" and for function is http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions so with these prefixes i could not be able to manage to execute the program. Can you please update your answer with the examples and result please?

Comment: What failure did you get? What XSLT processor were you using?

Comment: I am using both XML Spy and Oxgen Editor, The error is: XPST0003: Expected type name in SequenceType, found <function> for the <xsl:variable name="b64Input" as="bin:hex(translate($uuid, '-', ''))"/>

Comment: Corrected typo, the "as" attribute should of course be "select".